# Can this site get a higher visual contrast look?

Tags: feature-request, design

On my screen, the color of the questions is a light blue sitting on a lighter blue--this is, imo, just nowhere near the contrast that text on screens ought to have.  I can read it, but it's not crisp and it is quite unpleasant to read that way.  The visited link version is slightly darker but is still not high contrast enough.  For the visually impaired, it must be particularly bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The light-blue appears to be the hex-color "4ca3d7" and the background appears to be "FDFDFD". [According to this site, those combination of colors do not provide good contrast](http://juicystudio.com/services/luminositycontrastratio.php).

The [contrast ratio](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-WCAG20-20060427/appendixA.html#luminosity-contrastdef) is "2.74:1" based on the site's calculations for the combination of those two colors; the the threshold is set at 5:1 as recommended in the draft [WCAG 2.0 Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-WCAG20-20060427/guidelines.html#visual-audio-contrast).

Comment: Wow, excellently quantified back-up of my point, thank you.